# Output Items Size GNU Radio Block

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to write a custom GNU Radio block in Python. I have an array of bytes which I am trying to output so it can be written to the file via the file sink block.

When I simply set the output_items to be the data I want to be outputted:

```
output_items[0] = np.array(data,dtype=np.int8)
```

It does not work, the file is not the output.

When I do a loop over the size of the output_items, it works fine:

```
for i in range(len(output_items[0])):
       output_items[0][i] = 0
```

This works. Is there a way to specify the size of the output_items array I want? I thought I could accomplish this by returning the output size of the array but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **fill in** the values in the *output buffer*, which means overwriting the **contents** of `output_items[0]`, not overwriting the python element itself.

What'll work is:

```
 output_items[0][:] = np.array(data,dtype=np.int8)
```

Comment: When I do this I get an error "could not broadcast input array from shape (184) into shape (6964)." This makes sense to me as the data I want to output is 184 bits while the input data is 6964 bits

Comment: indeed. And that's by design!